# Fill PowerBI Desktop Parameter with Url Parameter

Tags: powerbi

I have a huge report and several users, that access powerBI with same account but not directly from app.powerbi.com. They use speciall web app.

Every user gets his own access token. 
PowerBI report has its parameter "access_token".

My report then executes ms sql function "fn_get_user_id(access_token)", which returns a user_id. 
After that data in report is filtered by that very user_id.

Now I want to publish my report and want to have an ability to pass that access_token as a query parameter in url. I know about "?filter= . . .", but not sure, that it can be applied here.

so, is it possible to map query parameter from url to report parameter?
[image]

Comment: So you can't distinguish between users because they are sharing an account? And you need them to instead manually provide their token and pass that into your query?

Comment: No point, one account or not. I have one report and want to decide, what data to show there depending on parameter.

Comment: Do you need to prevent one user from seeing another user's report? I.e., is it a security thing or just a viewing preference?

Comment: It’s a security thing, yes. Need to show same report to different people, but only that part of data, which is allowed to them.

Comment: What about [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls)?

Comment: Yes, rls - that's the thing, thank you!
But my question is still opened. 
Why doesn't Microsoft provide mapping of url-parameters with PowerBI Query Parameters, like it is already made in SSRS?